# Unable to install pychrono with Conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to install pychrono (physics library simulation for python), but I'm having troubles installing it.
I followed the installing guide at this link:https://api.projectchrono.org/development/pychrono_installation.html, but when I try to install pychrono I get this error in the terminal:

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

The problem is that Conda is not showing what packages are in fact incompatible so I can't figure out what's the problem.
I already tried to do new environments with previous versions of python but with no luck.
What am I missing?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.